# Running pig script every week on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cron, apache-pig

I have a pig script which I want to automatically execute every week on a hadoop cluster. 
Can I use a cron job to do this? How can I execute this solution? please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this using cron job. Wrap up the execution of the pig script with its relevant configurations and parameters in a unix script. Just schedule the script from crontab.
The execution command will be

pig (arguments) (script)